# Count non-matching rows as zero - how to?

Tags: mysql, sql

The thing, that I'm trying to do is:

Fetch room availability count based on supplied checkin and checkout dates.

Here are the tables:

```
categories

id | name
1  | Luxe
2  | Deluxe

reservations

id | category_id |  checkin    | checkout

1  |     1       | 2018-01-06  | 2018-01-10
1  |     2       | 2018-01-11  | 2018-01-13
3  |     2       | 2018-01-13  | 2018-01-17
```

Expected output

Since `category_id = 2` is available from `2018-01-06` up to `2018-01-10` (see the very first row in `reservations` table), I'm trying to include its availability count, when fetching total count.

So when running this query

```
SELECT 
    categories.name AS category,
    COUNT(reservations.id) AS free_count

FROM reservations 

INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = reservations.category_id

WHERE checkin BETWEEN '2018-01-06' AND '2018-01-10'

GROUP BY categories.name, reservations.id
```

The output is:

```
category | free_count

Luxe     |   1
```

However I'm willing the output to be:

```
category | free_count

Luxe     |   1
Deluxe   |   0
```

i.e replace non-matching rows to zero. How this can be done? A solution without nested queries (due to their slow performance) is very encouraged.

Comment: wrap your query to some `table x`, make a left join to categories table.

Comment: @Krishna Can you explain the point of wrapping? This merely creates an alias, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, since you already have non-zero results in this table that you already calculated, you will get 0 on non-matching rows if you do left-join on category table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT 
    c.name AS category,
    COUNT(r.id) AS free_count
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN reservations r 
       ON c.id = r.category_id
      AND checkin BETWEEN '2018-01-06' AND '2018-01-10'
GROUP BY c.name
```

Its important to keep the `checkin` filter in `ON` condition. When you keep the right table filter in `Where` clause, the non matching records will have `NULL` values which will be filtered in result due the `where` condition(basically `Left join` will be converted to `Inner join`)